# Tag for paracetamol

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [acetaminophen-pain-meds](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acetaminophen-pain-meds). However:

1. acetaminophen is more commonly known as paracetamol.
2. acetaminophen is not only an analgesic but also an antipyretic.

Hence, I propose that the tag be renamed [acetaminophen](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acetaminophen) with synonym [paracetamol](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paracetamol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implented as suggested in the question.